# i want to run delete row function if a certain column meets the conditions

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to delete multiple rows of data on condition if column B in that row is equal to CID parameter. but after I run it, the deleted data is incorrect. Sometimes the deleted data is located one row above or below the specified row in the for row loop
here is my code :

```
  if (e.parameter.func == "DeleteRec") {
    var rg=ss.getSheetByName("MAIN").getDataRange().getValues();   
    var lr= ss.getSheetByName("MAIN").getLastRow();
    for(var row=1;row<=lr;row++){
      var cid=rg[row].toString().split(',');
      if(cid[1]==e.parameter.CID){
        ss.getSheetByName("MAIN").deleteRow(row-1);
        var data=200;
       
      }
    }
       
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(data).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

You need to delete the rows from bottom-up or backwards because after you delete one row you change the structure of the spreadsheet file and therefore `rg` does not match the new structure of the sheet.

- Keep in mind that array indexes in JavaScript start from `0`. When variable `row` is `1` you want to delete `row+1` in the sheet, because `row=1` is getting the second element of your array.
- Calling `getSheetByName` in a `for` loop will increase the performance cost of your script. Instead, define the `sheet` variable before the loop so you can use it every time you need it.
- Since you are using [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) the length of `rg` is equal to what `getLastRow` returns. Therefore `lr` is not needed.
- Not sure why you iteratively assign a fixed value to a variable `var data=200` but I kept that part since it is not part of your question.

### Solution:

Replace the relevant part with this code:

```
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
const rg = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();   
for (var row = rg.length - 1; row>0; row--) {
    var cid=rg[row].toString().split(',');
    if(cid[1]==e.parameter.CID){
      sheet.deleteRow(row+1);
      var data=200;       
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the first row is a header

Comment: @TitanAnggaraksa `row>0` ensures `row` should be **at least 1** therefore it starts from the second row of your sheet. The header row will be ignored as it is in `row=0` . Remember, JavaScript indexes start from 0, namely the header in `rg` is in the zero position of the array and therefore it is ignored. Instead of `row>0` you can put `row>=1` if you feel more confident with that. It won't make any difference since it is the same expression :)